# how to retrieve data in a given time range with seconds negligable

Tags: mysql, datetime

I Have data like

```
Kysid     date coloumn 
1         2012-07-24 13:18:13
2         2012-07-24 13:18:12
3         2012-07-24 13:20:17
4         2012-07-24 13:20:34
5         2012-07-24 13:21:17
6         2012-07-24 13:21:34
```

from the above data i need to  get the 1,2,3,4 columns data with seconds term negotiable.how can i write query for that?
my query is

`select * from table where date_coloumn between ('2012-07-24 13:20:34') and date_sub('2012-07-24 13:20:34',interval 2 minute)`  .but it is not showing data

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE Date_coloumn BETWEEN '2012-07-24 13:18:00' AND '2012-07-24 13:20:00'
```

(Or)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE Date_coloumn >='2012-07-24 13:18:00' AND Date_coloumn <= '2012-07-24 13:20:00'
```

Comment: but for some data it will be some different value in seconds and it is creating problem.so i dont want to consider seconds part in comparison.how do i get it?